# I want vb script to send a email notification from remote machine which is in vpn network to my local machine

Tags: vbscript

I have the below code which works fine in local network. But I want the same feature to work for remote machine which I connect through vpn even when I am not logged in.

```
Function Sendmail()
    Dim objMessage
    Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    objMessage.Subject = "Checking for latest file"
    objMessage.From = "d@tkd.com"
    objMessage.To = "s@tkd.com"
    objMessage.TextBody = "This is to intimate you regrding latest File........."

    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2  

    'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mail.tkd.com"

    'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate" ) = cdoBasic

    'Your UserID on the SMTP server
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername" ) = "deepika@tecknodreams.com"

    'Your password on the SMTP server
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "123"

    'Server Port
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

    'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl" ) = False

    'Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection to the SMTP server)
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout" ) = 60


    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
    objMessage.Send
End Function
```

Comment: Please anyone help to do the above scenario.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Whether the example code below will work for you or not will depend entirely on your SMTP server's configuration.  If your server requires credentials in order to transmit an email, then this code will most likely fail for you.  If your server allows anonymous mail submission, it should work fine.

```
'
' Sends an email via SMTP using CDO
'
' When calling, supply:
'   fromAddress (e.g., "me@my.org")
'   toAddress   (e.g., "you@your.org")
'   subjectLine (e.g., "Here's what this message is about")
'   messageBody (e.g., "Here is a detailed message with lots of info...")
'   smtpServer  (e.g., "mail-server.my.org")
'
Sub sendEmail(fromAddress, toAddress, subjectLine, messageBody, smtpServer)

   Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1 'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory.
   Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).

   Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
   Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
   Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM


   Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
   objMessage.Subject = subjectLine
   objMessage.From = fromAddress
   objMessage.To = toAddress
   objMessage.TextBody = messageBody
   'objMessage.AddAttachment "C:\files\filename.pdf"

   objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort

   'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
   objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = smtpServer

   'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
   objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoAnonymous

   'Server port (typically 25)
   objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

   'Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection to the SMTP server)
   objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30

   objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

   '==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

   objMessage.Send


End Sub
```